# how to define a default for a JSON object value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

ive currently got a `JSON` string that gets returned as the result of an external system. as part of the object that gets returned there is a chance that some of the expected variables may not exist because the external system doesnt return anything if its not there.

example

```
data.columns.state.name
```

may not return state, but it may also not return many other objects as well if nothing is found to be populated in the external system.

is there an easy way to set up some defaults so that if it doesnt get returned, i have a variable ready and waiting... - thanks in advance

Comment: i think you will have to parse the string into json object and then check if each of the element contains a value by traversing the object.

Comment: will the structure of your JSON be static?? ie will you know exactly how many objects or arrays exist inside the JSON?? or will it vary alll the time??

Comment: with this object, the majority of the data will be there, but occasionally there may be portions that may not be. like state, zip. i was hoping for a shortcut way to define a variable prior to parsing the object so i know i always have a default in case

Comment: @user125264 check my answer and let me know if it helps

Comment: @user125264 Did you solve it? If so please share. I'm facing the same exact situation now, just that I have an array of nested json to be deserialized.

Answer (score 0):

This is really just a general programming question related to checking object values.  If your are getting a json string back you can parse it with the following line of code:

```
var json_obj = JSON.parse(pass_json_string_here)
```

json_obj will now be a normal javascript object and you can write whatever code you would like to test what values exist.  For example:

```
if (json_obj.state)
  {//do nothing
} 
else{
  json_obj.state = 'some value'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **[$.Extend](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/)** you can set the defaults, But this is limited only if you know the structure of the JSON.

Set a default value,

```
var jsonDefault =  {
    columns: {
        state: {
            name: 'default Name'
        }
    }
};
```

Then pass in your returned data into the extend function, This extend function will merge the two objects, And If there are any values in the second object it will be given priority.

```
$.extend({},jsonDefault.columns, returnedObject.columns);
```

Below is the working example, Here you can see the name is updated but the default value of zip is used, Also if there are new columns returning from your server even that is merged into the final result.

```js
var jsonDefault =  {   // just set all the required defaults.
    columns: {
        state: {
            name: 'default Name'
        },
        zip : "00000"
    }
};

var returnedObj ={   // this obj can have new properties too,
    columns: {
        state: {
            name: 'LA',
            order : 21
        }
    }
};

var result= $.extend({},jsonDefault.columns, returnedObj.columns); // results in merging the two objects and using the defaults where necessary

alert(JSON.stringify(result));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```